# Why is fetching data in next.js with hardcoded api-key working but not with environment variable?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, next.js

I followed the documentation of Next.js, so I created a file called .env.local and stored my API key inside.

**When console.logging that key it gets shown in the server-console and not in the browser console. So far I understand this.**

**Problem**: I want to fetch some data from the given URL. How can I get this done, without giving my API_KEY to the browser?

I think that topic is quite confusing for beginners (as me) and I an many other (so I think) would be overjoyed if anyone could get the confusion out of that.

Here is my code: (If I hardcode my API_KEY inside the URL it works fine)

```
import Haversine from '../components/Haversine'
import LangLat from '../components/LangLat'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const key = process.env.API_KEY

const index = () => {
  console.log(key)

  const getLangLat = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=wimpfener str 40 backnang&apiKey=${key}`
      )
      console.log(response.data)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message)
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getLangLat()
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <Haversine />
      <LangLat />
    </div>
  )
}

export default index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add NEXT_PUBLIC_ to the beginning of your environmental variable so you have access to it on the client side.

So inside of your .env.local change

API_KEY to NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY and do the same inside of your code.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#loading-environment-variables

Comment: And the key become readable for users from the browser, unfortunatly, no choice. But you can restrict your key to your host/domain in google console.

Comment: yes, that is the issue when you are calling API's from the client-side is that you need to provide your key publicly. There are other solutions such as server-side rendering inside of nextjs (https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) or moving your calls to your own API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @SirCodesAlot. Is this "moving your calls to your own API" possible through the "API routes" feature of next.js? I also used "getServerSideProps" and it works, but when I wnat to update the query inside of the API URL, I cant update it because getServerSide props only delivers the initial props...

Comment: MY SOLUTION: Using "Domain Whitelisting" which is provided by HERE and NEXT_PUBLIC_ as suggested by @SirCodesAlot. Thanks